# Extra margin under floated elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I am having an issue with the way my containers are constructed. I have two rows with two columns in each row. Think 4 quadrants (see image below). The bottom left quadrant is going up into the top right quadrant.

I am using floats to be able to switch positions for different viewports, so floats are a must. I have been stuck on this issue for a while and just can't seem to figure it out.

I included a snap show of what it is doing. Besides the bottom left quadrant entering the top-right one, there is a gap between rows.

I included a fiddle as well. Does anyone see what is going on?

[image]

[image]

```css
.section-blocks {
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.section-block-img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.left {
 float: left;
}
.right {
 float: right;
}

#company-information {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.company-information-block-title, .company-information-block-title2, .company-information-block-general-title, .company-information-block-description {
 color: #313743;
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
.company-information-block-title {
 font-size: 1.6em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.company-information-block-title2 {
 font-size: 3.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0085A1;
}
.company-information-block-general-title {
 font-size: 2.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.company-information-block-description {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}


#company-information-block2 {
 height: auto;
}

#company-slider-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div#slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#responsive-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#responsive-block1 {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 40%;
 position: relative;
}
#responsive-block2 {
 float: right;
 height: auto;
 width: 60%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#responsive-block2 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-blocks right">
   <div class="company-container">
    <div class="company-information-block-general-title">COMPANY STORY</div>
    <div class="company-information-block-description">
     <p>fdhsia  fid afdan fndsanfdn   fnfd fksanfanfd nfdanfan nfanafn dfnejwaoN F[gnf nr rnreogn aonrkngrnrnasng r narnrnoangrfkdkgraarmng aa arngrnga;aggkrioa   anrnr argnkrg gagnrgng g grkrn g g rgn e gan ggn as</p><br><br>
     <p>Ohtgfd htgdh thtrh trh rt sdfhh htsh shfh tsh sshh hs thhth shgsndfsank kfdnsak fndnkfdsa nkf f ndaiof nfasoanovn ndan fna gn an gnalnasgng agngna na nngfen grana akn gngaananogn</p>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><div id="company-slider-section">
   <div class="section-blocks left">
   <div id="slider" class="slider">
     <figure class="figure figure2">
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
      <div class="slide"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/es-test1.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
    </div>
     </figure>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="responsive-section">
  <div id="responsive-block1">
   <div class="company-container">
    <div class="company-information-block-general-title">INDUSTRY SPECIFIC</div>
    <div class="company-information-block-description"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="responsive-block2">
   <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/es-test3.jpg" alt>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You've got `margin-bottom` on  the `.block-title` elements.

Comment: Changing those to padding didn't correct this issue. Thanks though.

Comment: I never said you should change it to padding. Why not remove them?

Comment: Why would I remove them? I don't want the different titles to be touching.

Comment: If you don't want a gap nor the tiles to be touching, what do you want?

Comment: I want the containers to touch and for the industry specific title to be in the bottom left quadrant like it should be. My floated container is not positioning in the correct place.

Comment: `figure` elements have some margin by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can see would be to wrap your respective quadrants into rows with a `.clearfix` solution:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I am doing this correctly? https://jsfiddle.net/6yj6s90d/

Comment: You cannot apply `.clearfix` to a floated element as you are currently doing.  You need to wrap your entire "company" section in another `div` with a class of `.clearfix`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, buy why is there still a gap in between the two rows? https://jsfiddle.net/6yj6s90d/1/

Comment: @Becky `figure` element probably has default margins, also `img` may add extra margins if not set to `display: block`

Comment: @Oriol and @RemusGLS are correct - setting `figure { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` eliminates the gap.

Comment: Thanks! It was actually the missing `display: block;` to the images that was causing the margin issues...at least in my live element. I had a css element I didn't put in my fiddle that already had the figure's margin and padding set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both `float: left;` and `float: right`, just float it left. This would make the code easier to read as well.
You can put the "blocks" into "rows" to make sure they won't interfere with each other. By setting the blocks `overflow` you can make sure it "grows" with its children.

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section-blocks {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.section-block-img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.left {
 float: left;
}
.right {
 float: right;
}

#company-information {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.company-information-block-title, .company-information-block-title2, .company-information-block-general-title, .company-information-block-description {
 color: #313743;
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
.company-information-block-title {
 font-size: 1.6em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.company-information-block-title2 {
 font-size: 3.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0085A1;
}
.company-information-block-general-title {
 font-size: 2.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.company-information-block-description {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}


#company-information-block2 {
 height: auto;
}

#company-slider-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div#slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#responsive-section {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#responsive-block1 {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 40%;
 position: relative;
}
#responsive-block2 {
 float: right;
 height: auto;
 width: 60%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#responsive-block2 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="section-blocks">
    <div id="slider" class="slider">
      <figure class="figure figure2">
        <div class="slide-wrapper">
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/es-test1.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="section-blocks">
  <div class="company-container">
    <div class="company-information-block-general-title">COMPANY STORY</div>
    <div class="company-information-block-description">
      <p>fdhsia  fid afdan fndsanfdn   fnfd fksanfanfd nfdanfan nfanafn dfnejwaoN F[gnf nr rnreogn aonrkngrnrnasng r narnrnoangrfkdkgraarmng aa arngrnga;aggkrioa   anrnr argnkrg gagnrgng g grkrn g g rgn e gan ggn as</p><br><br>
      <p>Ohtgfd htgdh thtrh trh rt sdfhh htsh shfh tsh sshh hs thhth shgsndfsank kfdnsak fndnkfdsa nkf f ndaiof nfasoanovn ndan fna gn an gnalnasgng agngna na nngfen grana akn gngaananogn</p>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="responsive-section">
  <div id="responsive-block1">
    <div class="company-container">
      <div class="company-information-block-general-title">INDUSTRY SPECIFIC</div>
      <div class="company-information-block-description"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="responsive-block2">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/es-test3.jpg" alt>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```